# MVC Partial Page Refresh

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, asp.net-web-api

I am using `MVC` 5 to render an initial view and Kendo `MVVM` with `WebApi` to populate controls with data. The view returned from the controller is essentially a `SPA` application. After the initial render of the view all further activity on the page is achieved via Kendo `MVVM` and `WebApi` (client side script).

The menu for the application initially used `@Url.Action` links to present a new View. The issue with this approach is that a full page refresh redraws the entire screen including top and side navs every time an action link is clicked.

I replaced the `@Url.Action` links with `@Ajax.ActionLink` and modified the controllers to return Partial Views. The `@Ajax.ActionLink` enables the rendering of the Partial View into a target Html element (`div`).

Given the application is essentially a Html 5 application rather than a pure MVC application, is this the best way to avoid full page refresh on selection of a new menu item?

Secondly, should I be using `RenderBody()` or is there a better approach?

regards
Barry

Comment: You will need help from Jquery or Ajax to use either Get or POST to your WebAPI or just the controller. Just use the PartialView return. With a partial View item cshtml. If you don't need to contact the server side for this. Just use the jquery or for bindings, use KnockOUT JS.

RenderBody() is best used if you have a Layout file in the Shared Views Folder. If you don't want to use it, just take it off by Layout = null. Render Body is just a call like Include() in PHP. it doesn't really do much same as render Script but it make sure everything is ready before it runs the script.

Answer (score 0):

Try This sample jquery Code Button Or Any control click Or Control Change Event

```
var url= '/Service/Grid';
$("#DivID").load(url);
```